# lwarp does not allow section in different chapter to have same name. How to fix?

Tags: lwarp

I am not able to make a section with same title in different chapters using lwarp.

It will not let me have same section title even though they are in different chapters. It seems to create files with section names and this caused a problem if there is already a section with same name even though they are in different chapter.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[mathjax]{lwarp}
\usepackage{amsmath}     
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{FileDepth}{3} 
\setcounter{SideTOCDepth}{3} 


\begin{document}
\title{my page}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{this is chapter 1} 
\section{my first section} 
\subsection{my first subsection}
   text
\section{my second section}

\chapter{this is chapter 2} 
\section{my first section} 
\subsection{my first subsection}
   text
\section{my second section}% ---> commenting this removes the error
\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
lualatex foo.tex
lualatex foo.tex
lwarpmk html
```

gives

```
---
Package lwarp:
Processing MathJax customizations for the first HTML page.
Later HTML pages will take the same amount of time.
If this takes too long, see the Lwarp manual regarding customizing MathJax.
Done.
---
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./foo_html.toc) [2] [3] (./foo_html.sidetoc) [4] [5] [6] [7]
(./foo_html.sidetoc) [8] [9] (./foo_html.sidetoc) [10] [11] [12]

! Package lwarp Error: The section name:
(lwarp)                ``my second section'',
(lwarp)                at the line number listed below,
(lwarp)                generates the filename
(lwarp)                ``my-second-section'',
(lwarp)                which appears to be a duplicate. There is a
(lwarp)                previous section with an identical or similar name.
(lwarp)                While generating file names, Lwarp sanitizes math,
(lwarp)                most symbols, and a few common short words,
(lwarp)                and this may cause a conflict.
(lwarp)                Enter 'H' for possible solutions.

See the lwarp package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.27 \section{my second section}

?
```

The problem is this

```
>ls -lrt *.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me 58694 May 11 06:01 foo_html.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me 14973 May 11 06:01 this-is-chapter-2.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me 14937 May 11 06:01 this-is-chapter-1.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me 14594 May 11 06:01 my-second-section.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me 14031 May 11 06:01 foo.html
```

it creates file called `my-second-section.html` from first chapter and it does not want to make another file with same name for the section in the second chapter?

Can one not have same section title in lwarp? Is there a workaround?

TL 2022

Comment: did you try `Enter 'H' for possible solutions.` as the message you posted suggsted?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes I did. the solutions suggested makes no sense to me. It basically tells me I have duplicate section name. But I know this and this is valid and works in pdf and tex4ht. It says to change the name. `To avoid duplicate filenames, use the optional
short Table of Contents entry:
  \section[Unique name, no math]{Name with math}
or use \texorpdfstring, from the hyperref package:
  \section{
    \texorpdfstring
      {Name with math}{Unique name, no math}
  }
?`  If this is the only solution, then will not bother with lwarp any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It never hurts to do what an error mssage suggests.

The mssage in your question ends

```
(lwarp)                Enter 'H' for possible solutions.
```

But your log suggsts that you just scrolled past. `h`would produce the response

```
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.26 \section{my second section}
                              % ---> commenting this removes the error
? h
To avoid duplicate filenames, use the optional
short Table of Contents entry:
  \section[Unique name, no math]{Name with math}
or use \texorpdfstring, from the hyperref package:
  \section{
    \texorpdfstring
      {Name with math}{Unique name, no math}
  } 
?
```

I get

```
./my-second-section1.html
./my-second-section2.html
./this-is-chapter-1.html
./this-is-chapter-2.html
```

from

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[mathjax]{lwarp}
\usepackage{amsmath}     
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{FileDepth}{3} 
\setcounter{SideTOCDepth}{3} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{my page}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{this is chapter 1} 
\section{my first section} 
\subsection{my first subsection}
   text
\section[my second section\texorpdfstring{}{1}]{my second section}

\chapter{this is chapter 2} 
\section{my first section} 
\subsection{my first subsection}
   text
\section[my second section\texorpdfstring{}{2}]{my second section}% ---> commenting this removes the error
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I do not want to do this. I want to keep my document as is. I see nothing wrong with having the same section title in the document. It works OK in pdf and in tex4ht. I was looking for some setting I can give to lwarp to avoid this. Not change the  Latex document. It is a 50,000  pages document. I am not going to go change section and subsection and subsubsection names because lwarp does not allow same title, which is valid thing to do.

Comment: @Nasser what you do is of course your choice but not directly related to the question. The issue is documented both in the error help  and page 127 of the manual which says "Section names at levels which result in HTML file splits must be unique."  you could simply redefine section to add `\texorpdfsring{}\thechaper}` so the PDF isn' affeced but the filename gets the chapter number. Or put in a feature request at lwarp to include section numbers in fileames so they are unique.